# Display a Label and its value on change of dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to display a label and its value when a dropdown value is changed. 
For eg:-  when AddressType is changed then i want to display the AddressLine1 label and its respective value.

I am able to display the `<td></td>` part and the label also gets displayed. But the value of `Address1` is not getting displayed. I tried setting in `ViewBag` and then using it in `<td></td>` but that is not working. I tried to set the value of `displayFor` id also. but that too doesn't work.

How can i display the value ?

Code:

```
<td id="Address1Label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1)
</td>
<td id="Address">
    @this.ViewBag.AddressLine1
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address1,  new {@id = "Address1" })
</td>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Address1Label').hide();
    $('#Address').hide();
});

$(function () {
    $('#AddressType').change(function (e) {

        // i call an Action and get the result as json

        if (data.HomeAddress != null) {
            $('#Address1Label').show();
            $('#Address').show();

            // $('#Address1').val(data.HomeAddress.Address1);
            $('#Address1').html(data.HomeAddress.Address1);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far As I know

```
@Html.DisplayFor<TModel, TValue>
```

by default, ignore your overload html attributes which means

```
<td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Address1,  new {@id = "Address1" }) </td>
```

only produce an text like

```
<td> Address </td>
```

instead of what you may think like

```
<td><xxx id="Address1"> Address </xxx></td>
```

So if you want to change this value, you can do

```
$('#Address').html(data.HomeAddress.Address1);
```